# Walking/jogging/sprinting causes pain in the abdomen?

Tags: running, pain, walking

I usually walk 3 miles a day (other than at gym), whereas at the gym I stay on treadmill for 20 minutes juggling between walk, jog and sprint.

When I run quite for some time, I get a shooting pain at the right side of my abdomen! Not just this, at times when I walk quite a lot in any environment I get the same kinda pain.
Also, the issue is not steady, it happens only when I breathe IN. And only till I am breathing little heavier than normal.

So, what might be the cause? What precautions should I take to not let this increase? Above all how do I make it right?

P.S - I don't remember this happening even once when I lift weights.

Stats -

Weight - 95 kg.
Height - 185 cm.
Been working out irregularly for 4-5 months.

Comment: Just a note you get out what you put in: Irregular workouts will give irregular results hence you will get a stitch in your side

Comment: By irregular I meant, I did workout for 4 months and stopped and after 6 months am moving back to gym!

Answer (score 2):

Based on your description this sounds like a very common side stitch (see the wiki entry here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Side_stitch).

As explained in the article (which was informative for me even though I have experienced these off and on when exercising for as long as I can remember) there can be a few factors causing this. For me, it generally related to dehydration, or pushing too hard on my runs after not having run for some time). When this occurs for me stretching my right side (placing my right arm over my head, grabbing with my left arm and slowly leaning/pulling left so my entire right side is stretched), regulating my breathing, and drinking water have helped to relieve. Although sometimes the wait for recovery made it so that my running session was over for that period in time (If I wait 5-10 minutes, all was usually good).

Could be completely different causes for you, but read up on side stitches and see if this is indeed what is occurring and if any of the recommended preventions help you out.

Good luck.